# CSS menu with links on tablet device

Tags: css, menu, tablet

On desktop view (with mouse) the hover menu is as expected, however on tablet (touch), the menu automatically selects the hyperlink. How can the menu not link to the page when I touch it?

```
<nav id="menu1">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Item 1a</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Item 1aa</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><div class="a1">Item 1aa<img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2344/5764645658_1498022e55.jpg" alt="1" height="200" width="200"></div></nav>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh96tfft/) example

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript for that, what you have to do is to see if it's a mobile device, if so,show the next submenu when it is clicked once, and go to the link when it is double clicked.
for one click use : onclick="showsubmenu()"
for double click use : ondblclick="gotopage()"